# Wget download pdf

Tags: unix, wget

I am trying to download a pdf file using *wget*.

When I do:

`wget <url>` it downloads a corrupted file however if I run `wget -i test.txt` with the pdf URL inside this test txt file it works and the file is not corrupted.

Does anyone know why?

**From the logs I can see the following.**

In the first case, it is downloading a note found page.

> Length: 11322 (11K) [text/html] Saving to: ‘media.nl?id=39194.1’

In the second it is a proper pdf.

> Length: 58272 (57K) [application/pdf] Saving to:
>   ‘media.nl?id=39194&c=4667446&h=34c63dbaaa7adc7c8a33&_xt=.pdf’

Thanks,

Comment: When you say corrupted file, is it still a PDF file which is getting downloaded ? and what is the error you get when you open it ?

Comment: @rootkonda No, it is not. It downloads a not found html page.

Comment: I believe this happens for any pdf right ? try this - https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

Comment: No, it works with your dummy pdf. It is not for this one https://www.roofingsuppliesuk.co.uk/core/media/media.nl?id=39194&c=4667446&h=34c63dbaaa7adc7c8a33&_xt=.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Put your URL into quotes. Not quoting the URL can lead to strange effects, in your case the `&` is interpreted by the shell.

E.g.

```
wget "https://www.roofingsuppliesuk.co.uk/core/media/media.nl?id=39194&c=4667446&h=34c63dbaaa7adc7c8a33&_xt=.pdf"
```

or

```
wget 'https://www.roofingsuppliesuk.co.uk/core/media/media.nl?id=39194&c=4667446&h=34c63dbaaa7adc7c8a33&_xt=.pdf'
```

or with escaping of `&`

```
wget https://www.roofingsuppliesuk.co.uk/core/media/media.nl?id=39194\&c=4667446\&h=34c63dbaaa7adc7c8a33\&_xt=.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue but I changed the command to this and then it worked fine when i tested it:

Wget —-no-check-certificate https://www.roofingsuppliesuk.co.uk/core/media/'media.nl?id=39194&c=4667446&h=34c63dbaaa7adc7c8a33&_xt=.pdf'

i just added single quotes beginning at 'media.nl.......pdf'

Make sure the file with same name doesnt exist. You dont need to add --no-check-certificate if you dont get self-signed certificate error